# Python: cImage, writing a function that takes an image and another function

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write the following.

> Write the contract and implementation for a procedure generalTransform that takes an image and a procedure that transforms a pixel and returns a new image with all the original pixels transformed by the given procedure.

We were supposed to write other functions as well as part of this assignment.  I'm listing those below as I use them.  What they do is written in the docString.

```
def sepiaTone(p):
    """ which calls for writing a pixel function for sepia toning"""
    red = p.getRed()
    green = p.getGreen()
    blue = p.getBlue()
    newR = (red * .393 + green*.769 + blue * .189)
    if newR > 254:
        newR = 255
    newG = (red * .349 + green*.686 + blue * .168)
    if newG > 254:
        newG = 255
    newB = (red * .272 + green*.534 + blue * .131)
    if newB > 254:
        newB = 255
    newPixel = (newR,newG,newB)
    return newPixel
```

.

```
def gammaTwo(p):
    """takes a pixel and performs a gamma correction with the gamma value of 2.0."""
    R = p.getRed()
    G = p.getGreen()
    B = p.getBlue()
    Y = 0.00117 * R + 0.00230 * G + 0.000447 * B
    Y2 = Y**2
    U = -0.000577 * R - 0.00113 * G + 0.00171 * B
    V = 0.00241 * R - 0.00202 * G - 0.00039 * B
    R = 255 * (Y2 + 1.13983 * V)
    G = 255 * (Y2 - 0.39465 * U - 0.58060 * V)
    B = 255 * (Y2 + 2.03211 * U)
    if R > 254:
         R = 255
    if G > 254:
        G = 255
    if B > 254:
        B = 255
    newPixel = (R,G,B)
    return newPixel
```

.

```
def gammaHalf(p):
    """takes a pixel and performs a gamma correction with the gamma value of 0.5""""
    R = p.getRed()
    G = p.getGreen()
    B = p.getBlue()
    Y = 0.00117 * R + 0.00230 * G + 0.000447 * B
    Y2 = Y**.5
    U = -0.000577 * R - 0.00113 * G + 0.00171 * B
    V = 0.00241 * R - 0.00202 * G - 0.00039 * B
    R = 255 * (Y2 + 1.13983 * V)
    G = 255 * (Y2 - 0.39465 * U - 0.58060 * V)
    B = 255 * (Y2 + 2.03211 * U)
    if R > 254:
         R = 255
    if G > 254:
        G = 255
    if B > 254:
        B = 255
    newPixel = (R,G,B)
    return newPixel
```

.

```
def rotate(image):
    """takes an image and returns an image of the original image rotated 90 degrees clockwise"""
    pic = FileImage(image)
    oldw = pic.getWidth()
    oldh = pic.getHeight()
    myWin = ImageWin("Wild", oldw*2, oldh*2)
    pic.draw(myWin)
    newIm = EmptyImage(oldw,oldw)
    for row in range (oldh):
        for col in range(oldw):
            oldPx = pic.getPixel(col,row)
            newIm.setPixel(oldw-row,col,oldPx)

    newIm.setPosition(oldh+1,0)
    newIm.draw(myWin)
```

Now here's where I'm having the problem.  This function  When I run it I get an error

Function,

```
def generalTransform(image, pro):
    """takes an image and a procedure that transforms a pixel and returns a new image with all the original pixels transformed by the given procedure."""
    pic = FileImage(image)
    h = pic.getHeight()
    w = pic.getWidth()
    myWin = ImageWin('Wild', w, h)
    pic.draw(myWin)
    newIm = EmptyImage (w,h)
    for row in range (h):
        for col in range (w):
            p = pic.    getPixel(col, row)
            pro(p)

    newIm.draw(myWin)
```

Error Message:  I don't know what to make of it.  Where am I going wrong?  wildLogo.gif is the correct name of the image for the record.

```
generalTransform("wildLogo.gif", rotate)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    generalTransform("wildLogo.gif", rotate)
  File "C:\Python33\image.py", line 92, in generalTransform
    pro(p)
  File "C:\Python33\image.py", line 99, in rotate
    pic = FileImage(image)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cImage.py", line 398, in __init__
    super(FileImage, self).__init__(fname = thefile)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cImage.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.loadImage(fname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cImage.py", line 270, in loadTkImage
    sufstart = fname.rfind('.')
AttributeError: 'Pixel' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: If you look carefully, you're calling `rotate` with a pixel as parameter when it's actually expecting an image.